# Icons do not appear in ApplicationBar

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Icons do not appear in ApplicationBar.

MainPage.xaml.cs

```
// Конструктор
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Локализация ApplicationBar
        BuildLocalizedApplicationBar();
    }

    // ApplicationBar
    private void BuildLocalizedApplicationBar()
    {
        // Установка нового экземпляра ApplicationBar.
        ApplicationBar = new ApplicationBar();

        // Задаем опции
        ApplicationBar.Mode = ApplicationBarMode.Default;
        ApplicationBar.Opacity = 1.0;
        ApplicationBar.IsVisible = true;
        ApplicationBar.IsMenuEnabled = true;

        // Кнопка "Add"
        ApplicationBarIconButton Add = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/Add.png", UriKind.Relative));
        Add.Text = AppResources.AppBarAdd;
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(Add);
        Add.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Add_Click);

        // Кнопка "Edit"
        ApplicationBarIconButton Edit = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/Edit.png", UriKind.Relative));
        Edit.Text = AppResources.AppBarEdit;
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(Edit);
        Edit.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Edit_Click);

        // Кнопка "Delete"
        ApplicationBarIconButton Delete = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/Delete.png", UriKind.Relative));
        Delete.Text = AppResources.AppBarDelete;
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(Delete);
        Delete.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Delete_Click);

        // Кнопка "Connect"
        ApplicationBarIconButton Connect = new ApplicationBarIconButton(new Uri("/Assets/AppBar/Connect.png", UriKind.Relative));
        Connect.Text = AppResources.AppBarConnect;
        ApplicationBar.Buttons.Add(Connect);
        Connect.Click += new EventHandler(Button_Connect_Click);

    }
```

Icons in the folder / Assets / AppBar / is, standard icons, pulled out of most SDK, size 76x76, for Dark theme.

The problem on the emulator and on the phone.

Comment: Did you add the icons to your project?

Comment: I just moved the folder icons in Debug. Screenshot: http://img.5cm.ru/view/i5/kajK.png   The problem exists.

Comment: You need to add the icons to the **project** as well. In Visual Studio select folder Assets. Right click on it, select Add Existing Items... In the dialog box navigate to you folder on disk and select the files you want to add (Add.png, Edit.png and Delete.png in your case).

Comment: Try following this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff431806(v=vs.105).aspx to ensure your icons are accessible by the project. You will also have issues with the size as well so once you get it displaying you'll most likely need to tweak those details to get the look you want.